# Laravel - Routing issue with resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Im new to Laravel and just ran into a problem. I got these two routes.

```
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostController@show'); // To show the post
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

The problem is when i want to go to /posts/create tries to send me to the show function, but ofcourse can find the object. What am i doing wrong? So i thinks the word "create" is an id.

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: I'd personally use HTTP POST on 'posts/' to create a new one.

Comment: yes you will get "create" as passing variable in method `show`. You can handle it in controller or you can create an new route.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you do not have RESTful path binded to correct route.
I recommend you to define posts also as resource like this

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Now you have all the RESTful paths automatically created and calling /posts/create will be handled by the create method in controller.